# NTP with GPS offset

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps, clock, ntp

I tried to get accurate clock (bellow the millisecond precision) in a Raspberry Pi 3, using a GPS with PPS support (Adafruit Ultimate GPS V3).

Configured the NTPd using the driver 46: http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/drivers/driver46.html

GPSd with both the GPS serial port and the PPS configured in the kernel and set in the config file (confirmed working with ppstest).

But even after hours running, the offset of the source is in the range of -50 to 50 milliseconds. 
Plot of the peerstats file bellow:
[image: Peerstats plot]

The output of `ntpq -crv -pn`:

```
associd=0 status=0438 leap_none, sync_uhf_radio, 3 events, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sat Mar 10 18:03:33 UTC 2018 (1)",
processor="armv7l", system="Linux/4.9.78-v7+", leap=00, stratum=1,
precision=-19, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=4.236, refid=GPSD,
reftime=e00701aa.7800bb3a  Thu, Feb  7 2019 19:12:42.468,
clock=e00701ab.c3643a08  Thu, Feb  7 2019 19:12:43.763, peer=60820, tc=3,
mintc=3, offset=1.296237, frequency=-6.309, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=15.046, clk_wander=4.507
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*127.127.46.0    .GPSD.           0 l    1    8  377    0.000    1.296  10.039
```

Should not be possible to get a better accuracy?

Comment: Can you show your `ntp.conf` file (or at least the lines relating to the `gps` sources)? It also looks like it might be using `NMEA` timing rather than the `PPS` - I Use driver [28](http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/drivers/driver28.html)

Comment: Supposedly  driver 46 combines both the PPS and the NMEA on the GPSD... But I have other device configured with driver 28 and driver 22 (PPS) and suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Do you have a `fudge` factor set?

Comment: I don't. But wouldn't a fudge factor just move the skew up or down for a X amount of time?

Comment: There are a couple of flags you can set - I don't remember them to hand but 2 & 3 come to mind. I don't have access to a production box at the moment to check but I do use a mix of other drivers. Just 1 thing; have you confirmed through `gpsd` you are *actually* getting a `pps` from your device ?

Comment: Yes I had confirm it had pps in gpsd. In cgps shown in the output the line:  `{"class":"PPS","device":"/dev/pps0","real_sec":1550247028, "real_nsec":0,"clock_sec":1550247027,"clock_nsec":785231062,"precision":-20}`

Comment: I use a very old version of `gpsd` in production as the newest ones gave me troubles. here are the stats from a production box; `xSHM(0)          .GPS.            0 l    6   16  377    0.000   -3.889  12.227
*SHM(1)          .PPS.            0 l   14   16  377    0.000    0.035   0.111` but i only ever use the `SHM` driver

Comment: Ty, those stats look good, except for the jitter on the first on. But could be temporary. Do you have any log of the peerstats?

Comment: The jitter on the first is caused by the NMEA and is *normal* on most of my systems. I'll have a look and see if I have peer stats once I'm back later for you.

Comment: I've got some peer stats logging from a production box if you want me to post it somewhere?

Comment: Gist.github.com would be great @user3788685. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Sorry don't have an account there but have uploaded  [here](http://www.zen115228.zen.co.uk/ntp/ntpstats.tar.gz) for you. There are peerstats & loop stats for a full day on 19/02/19 from a production box. The peerstats have had the first 2 blocks of the IP replaced with xxx.xxx